# Deserializing Json string c#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize the following json into a C# object? I need to read density and the coordinates. Can someone please check if the json is correct and the best way to get the data into C# object?

```
{{
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      51.5570726284386,
      25.39156280708102
    ]
  },
  "density": 1
}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It does not look like a valid JSON. As for generally deserializing JSON in C# - there are plenty of examples of that on the web, try something first.

Comment: If you are using visual studio, click Edit>Paste Special>Paste Json as Class. Then you will have the class for your object. Deserialize your object into the class

Answer (score -2, accepted):

your json is not valid. But if you remove an extra braket at the start and the end of a string

```
json = json.Substring(1,json.Length-2);
```

then you can parse it

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

int density = (int)jsonObject["density"];
double[] coordinates = jsonObject["geometry"]["coordinates"].ToObject<double[]>();
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed the extra bracket and it works.

Answer (score -2):

Use `Parse(...)`:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(json);
var density = d["density"];
```

Comment: Using `dynamic` is a very bad practice. Ideally, you would want to convert the JSON to an object using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, but if you can't it's better to just keep the type as `JObject` as it will have the same functionality and is less ambiguous.